# MP3 File can't be properly converted by any program, always gets cut to <1 second in length

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, mp3, sox

I can't for the life of me figure this out, there's an mp3 file I'm trying to convert to wav with 1 channel on a linux server.

I always use sox however sox happily converts it exactly how I want, except it's trimmed down to slightly less than 1 second. I installed and tried ffmpeg but it did the same. I tried another program and it did the same.

I thought maybe there's just something really weird with the file so i piped it through a random online converter and it converted just fine but when I touch the newly converted file from the random online editor with one of those 3 programs it again converts A-OK but the file is back down to slightly less than a second so that trick didn't work.

How can a file do this and what do I do to make the file work normally in sox or ffmpeg conversions like every other audio file I use that never gives me these problems.

Comment: For now I've found a temporary fix which is just using the mp3 file as-is but I'm still curious how to fix this.

Comment: Share full log of the ffmpeg attempt.